# Webcam.js Internet explorer USB camera not detected

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, usb, webcam, getusermedia

Hello I'm trying to take a snapshot with Webcam.js on two condition's:

1. must run on internet explorer (since I use activeX in other matter).
2. must be with USB camera and not built in camera.

of course getUserMedia WORKS great and detect the camera. but cant make it on IE
with any replacement I found.
any suggestions ?

Comment: The webcam of choice has to do with the computer and OS. JavaScript controls the Browser, not the camera. It just lets you access the camera.

Comment: i disabled my built in webcam. and it works with getUserMedia. but when my app runs on IE webcam.js switches to flash and then it displays only built in webcam and not USB

Comment: **Update flash player detects the camera but displays white image